# How to center a character that is larger than its container

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms, css-tables

I have icons that I want centered both horizontally and vertically.

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/angrybacon/pen/rrNVgO?editors=1100) and snippet below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.icon-placeholder {
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 34px;
}
.icon {
  color: hotpink;
  font-size: 400%;
}
.icon::before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-placeholder">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

How can I do that regardless of `.icon`'s font size.

I have tried `transform`, `position: absolute`, `display: table` with no luck. I can't use flex.

Comment: [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On thing to note though, a `+` isn't necessarily centered in the first place depending on the font.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.icon-placeholder {
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 34px;
}

.icon {
  color: hotpink;
  font-size: 400%;
}

.icon::before {
  content: '0';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-placeholder">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `transform` and `absolute` positioning

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.icon-placeholder {
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 34px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  color: hotpink;
  font-size: 400%;
  margin-top: -10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;  
}
.icon::before {
  content: '+';
}

.plus-symbol{
  font-size: 400%;
  outline: dotted 1px red;
  color: hotpink;
}

.left, .right{
  width: 45%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}
.right{
  float: right;
}

.custom-plus-icon, .custom-plus-icon:before{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.custom-plus-icon:before{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <h3>Plus symbol using font</h3>
  <span class="plus-symbol">+</span>

  <br/>
  <br/>

  <label>Font-size : 400%</label>
  <div class="icon-placeholder">
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
  <label>Font-size : 300%</label>
  <div class="icon-placeholder">
    <span class="icon" style="font-size: 300%;"></span>
  </div>
  <label>Font-size : 200%</label>
  <div class="icon-placeholder">
    <span class="icon" style="font-size: 200%;"></span>
  </div>
  <label>Font-size : 100%</label>
  <div class="icon-placeholder">
    <span class="icon" style="font-size: 100%;"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <h3>Plus symbol using pseudo element</h3>
  <div class="icon-placeholder">
    <span class="custom-plus-icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do the `12%` come from?

Comment: `margin-top: -12%` was added to center the plus symbol inside the box. The font probably has a whitespace at top which amounts to 12% of the font size.

Comment: This is not a sane solution. This whitespace doesn't always equal to 12%.

Comment: It varies from font to font.. If you vary the font-size the plus sign will still be centered without the need to alter the margin-top value. All the fonts maintain the proportion of whitespace for varying font size. You would have to change the `margin-top` value only in case you change the `font-family`

Comment: Still, whitespace doesn't always equal to 12%.

Comment: It may not be always 12%. But if your font remains the same then 12% might help you get it centered. Alternatively you can make use of span to create the plus sign instead of using font which will give you better control over positioning.